# Finding a point in 3D space given the distance and angle

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I'm coding a tree generation script that outputs the coordinates of the trees and it's parts. For slightly more realism I had the trunk of the tree be multiple parts that rotate slightly (max is about 5 degrees for each axis.) But I need to calculate the end points of each trunk part, as so that each part aligns with each other.
In other words I am trying to find the end point of a line in 3d space given the rotation of the line, the position of the line (X, Y, Z), and the angle of the line (X, Y, Z).

I've searched for hours trying to find the equations, but have not gotten anywhere.

This is the closest I have, but every time I input the coordinates it outputs into Desmos 3D, the X-axis seems to be not calculated correctly. So I'm not sure if it's just the X-axis equation, or if all of the equations are wrong.

```py
def findEndpoints(trunkSection, rotX=None, rotY=None, rotZ=None):
    if rotX is None or rotY is None or rotZ is None:
        rotX, rotY, rotZ = trunkSection.angleX, trunkSection.angleY, trunkSection.angleZ, 
    posX, posY, posZ = trunkSection.Pos.X, trunkSection.Pos.Y, trunkSection.Pos.Z
    length = trunkSection.Size.X / 2

    X1 = posX - length * -(math.sin(rotY) * math.cos(rotZ))
    Y1 = posY - length * -(math.sin(rotX) * math.sin(rotY) * math.cos(rotZ) - math.cos(rotX) * math.sin(rotZ))
    Z1 = posZ - length * -(math.cos(rotX) * math.sin(rotY) * math.cos(rotZ) + math.sin(rotX) * math.sin(rotZ))

    X2 = posX + length * -(math.sin(rotY) * math.cos(rotZ))
    Y2 = posY + length * -(math.sin(rotX) * math.sin(rotY) * math.cos(rotZ) - math.cos(rotX) * math.sin(rotZ))
    Z2 = posZ + length * -(math.cos(rotX) * math.sin(rotY) * math.cos(rotZ) + math.sin(rotX) * math.sin(rotZ))

    endPoint1 = Vector(X1, Y1, Z1)
    endPoint2 = Vector(X2, Y2, Z2)

    return endPoint1, endPoint2
```

I've tried changing the signs, not negating it, etc.

Comment: If you look at the matrix in the Wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix, you'll see that the X transform needs to look much more like the Y and Z transforms.'

Comment: Hi. What does the tree look like? It's hard to visualise what you want to do just by reading your description of it. Do you have a hand-drawing of what you want to achieve?